# how to find num and denum of a given function?

Tags: matlab

I want to seperate a rational function to num and denom:
i.e x*y/(2*z) ===>  n = x*y      d = 2*z

here is my code:

```
func = input('Enter the function: ');
[n d] = numden(func);
disp(n);

>> test
Enter the function: x*y/(2*z)
??? Error using ==> input
Undefined function or variable 'y'.

Error in ==> test at 1
func = input('Enter the function: ');
```

Comment: Is the string always on this form, with one slash and your wanting to find the parts on the left and right?

Comment: It could be in any form, for example: x/y/z which is equal to x/(y*z)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [symbolic objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/syms.html).

```
>> syms x y;     
>> [n d] = numden(x*y/(x+y))

n =

x*y


d =

x + y

>>
```

Comment: >> syms x y;
??? Undefined function or method 'syms' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Comment: I think you need the Symbolic Math Toolbox. Do you have it installed?